# Equation for Length of Cubic Spline Between 3 Points

Tags: spline, cubic

This is my first time posting here, so I hope this is ok. I'm working on a java project but my question is really about the math I'll be using for it...

I have three (different) points at (x1, y1), (x2, y2), and (x3, y3). All I need is a formula for the length of the cubic spline formed between them. For someone good at calculus, this should be pretty easy to derive. I've looked all around online but can't seem to find the solution. Again, I don't even need the equation of the spline - just its length, given the three points. Thanks in advance! If someone can figure this out and share, you'll makey day :)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Math

Comment: Splines are used in computer graphics a lot, e.g. for visualization and movement/tweening.

Answer (score 1):

I have some bad news.

The first is that a cubic b-spline generally takes 4 points to define.  It is possible to define one from 3 points, but it usually involves making up another point somehow (for example, using degree elevation).  So we'd need to have information about how exactly you're defining the spline - if it's some other kind of spline (catmull-rohm?), or the details of how you're constructing it.

The second is that there's no closed-form equation for the length of a b-spline, or even a Bezier curve.  What I typically do is sample the curve at a lot of points, and then compute the length of the polyline.

There are formulas that can tell you what your error bound will be, based on the derivatives of the curve, and there are methods that approximate using arcs rather than line segments, but those are probably more complicated than they're worth.

Answer (score 0):

See the [primer on bezier curves](http://pomax.github.io/bezierinfo/) for a more info.  However, sadly, tfinniga is correct for cubic splines you need to use an approximation.